# avoid cookie duplicate in jmeter with JSR223 preprocessor

Tags: cookies, jmeter, jsr223

I am using a JSR 223 preprocessor to generate cookie from a text file and it works just fine. However, this cookie gets duplicated on every HTTP sampler request i have.
How can i avoid this ?

My testplan structure is :

testplan

-CookieManger

--testFragment

---JSR223 PreProcessor

----Transaction controller

-----HTTP request1

-----HTTP request2

-----HTTP request3

-----HTTP request4

in the first http request the cookie appear just once, however on HTTP request 2,3,4 the cookie is duplicated 2,3,4 times even though i checked the "clear cookie each itteration" in the cookie manager. How can i avoid this ?

Please note i'm a beginner to jmeter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware of [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules), given the current placement of the JSR223 PreProcessor it will be executed **before every HTTP Request** sampler.

The easiest workaround is just moving it to be **a child** of the HTTP Request 1

Alternatively you can check the presence of cookie and add it only if it's absent, something like:

```
if (sampler.getCookieManager().getCookies().find { cookie -> cookie.getName().equals('your-cookie-name-here') } != null) {
    //the code to add cookie from the text file here
}
```

More information: [Modifying Cookies in JMeter with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/modifying-cookies-in-jmeter-with-groovy)